# Python суммирования в dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Начал изучать Python и столкнулся с проблемой. Мне надо суммировать все значения, что находятся в словаре, пробовал через `sum(mydict.values())`, но оно выводит только последнее значения в словаре, а все предыдущие значения пропускает. Знаю, что вопрос может оказаться для кого-то легким, но может в будущем это кому-то пригодится.

```
sums={'suma': 274.6243,
 140.6846,
 1168.3088,
 657.7995,
 7.7,
 591.7394,
 543.3994,
 121.836,
 259624.1855,
 1200.8789,
 271.6997,
 271.6997,
 545.0,
 3.15,
 22.24,
 308.4797,
 3.15,
 2199.6225,
 4375.3625,
 7.7,
 43.62,
 7.7,
 543.3994,
 81.26,
 279.6997,
 87.516,
 0.0,
 4295.9209,
 0.5688,
 126.984,
 286.2397,
 2475.852,
 3.1988,
 584.74,
 183.2181,
 716.0388,
 22.0,
 1086.7989,
 7.7,
 212.11,
 1262940816.0582,
 279.3997,
 165.6996,
 271.6997,
 4941.7034,
 2024.3652,
 129.1241,
 44.0,
 9.45,
 271.6997}

        for i in range(len(sums)):
            suma=sum(sums[i].values())

            print(suma)
```

Comment: Такого словаря не может быть - один ключ и много значений. Вы что-то путаете.

Comment: А в вашем коде вы вообще пытаетесь обращаться к  элементу словаря по числовому индексу - словари так не умеют.

Comment: @Xander Вполне возможно, я неправильно начал создавать словарь и сделал его так что в один ключи много значений. Сейчас попробую сделать так как только что ответил снизу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sums = {'suma':
              [ 274.6243,
                140.6846,
               1168.3088,
                657.7995,
                  7.7,
               # ...
             ]
       }

print(sum(sums['suma']))
2249.1171999999997
```

---

**Update**

Начнем с того, что строка `sums={'suma': 274.6243, 140.6846, 1168.3088, 657.7995, 7.7}`
Выдает ошибку `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Словари в Python - неупорядоченные коллекции произвольных объектов с доступом по ключу.
Данные в словаре хранятся в формате `ключ: значение`.
Доступ к элементу словаря, осуществляется как же как доступ к элементу списка, 
только в качестве индекса указывается ключ.

```
d1 = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
d1["key1"]  # ---> 'value1'
```

Словарь может хранить вложенные словари. 
Словарь может хранить в качестве значений объекты любого типа (heterogeneous).
Ключ в словаре — immutable тип, может быть `строкой`, `целым числом`, `float` либо `кортежем`, 
состоящим из указанных типов.

С помощью словарей можно хранить структурированную информацию в виде записей:

```
myDict = {'key1': {'suma': [ 274.6243, 140.6846, 1168.3088, 657.7995, 7.7, ]},
          'key2': {'suma': [ 274.6243, 140.6846, 1168.3088, 657.7995, 7.7, ]},
          'key3': {'suma': [ 274.6243, 140.6846, 1168.3088, 657.7995, 7.7, ]},
         }

for k, v in myDict.items():
    print("{} : {}".format(k, sum(v['suma'])))

key1 : 2249.1171999999997
key2 : 2249.1171999999997
key3 : 2249.1171999999997
```

Comment: пишет ошибку TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @Key не пишет. Вы что-то не так делаете.